# How to insert block of actions in XML Literals before inserting new tag

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-literals

Help me please to understand how possible to insert inside XML Literals in VB.NET block of some actions like this:
iCol = iCol + 1
iTMP = iTmp + iCol
(for example in Loop i need to increase some variable before insertinf New Tag )

```
Dim objDoc As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
. . .
<%= From i In Enumerable.Range(3, LastRow)
Where UCase(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("Y" + CStr(i)).Value) = "Y" Select
iCol = iCol + 1
iTMP = iTmp + iCol
<TagWithData>Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("Y" + CStr(iTMP)).Value</TagWithData>
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

XmlLiterals are designed for binding data into the XDocument. If you have something more complicated you wish to do then try declaring an anonymous function and binding that instead.

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Dim myFunc = Function()
                     i += 1
                     Return i
                 End Function

    Dim doc = <xml>
                  <%= myFunc() %>
              </xml>
```

This has the benefit of removing more complicated logic out of the document.